# Drawing on image and saving

Tags: image, visual-c++, graphics, bitmap, c++-cli

I guess I don't really understand how Graphics objects work in Visual C++ 2010 Express.

I am grabbing a frame from a webcam, and drawing a circle on it. It works great on the screen. I simply create a Graphics object, draw the image, and draw the ellipse.

In the pictureBox_paint function, I have

```
Graphics^ g = e->Graphics; // from the camera 

System::Drawing::Rectangle destRect = System::Drawing::Rectangle(0,0,pbCameraMonitor->Size.Width,pbCameraMonitor->Size.Height);
double slitHeightToWidth = 3;
g->DrawImage(this->currentCamImage,destRect);
int circleX, circleY;
circleX = (int) (pbCameraMonitor->Size.Width - radius/slitHeightToWidth)/2;
circleY = (int) (pbCameraMonitor->Size.Height - radius)/2;

g->DrawEllipse(Pens::Red, circleX, circleY, (int) radius/slitHeightToWidth, (int) radius);
```

So far so good, my ellipse gets drawn on there nicely. The destRect bit makes sure it is scaled to the pictureBox size. I simply invalidate the pictureBox every time the camera reports a new image, and I have video.

Now, on a button click I want to save this image, with the red ellipse on it. However, I don't want the rescaled version shown on the screen, I want the full res version. So, I'll grab another frame into a Bitmap^ called "grabbedFrame" and do this:

```
String ^photofile = "Image_" + expRecord.timestamp.ToString("s") + ".jpg"; // get a unique filename
photofile = photofile->Replace(':', '_');
Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(grabbedFrame);
g->DrawEllipse(Pens::Red, 20, 20, 20, 20);  // circle size fixed just for demo
grabbedFrame->Save(photofile, System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageFormat::Jpeg);
```

When I do that, I get a save of the image without the red circle.

Does g->DrawEllipse actually modify the Bitmap? Or just contain the Bitmap + instructions to draw? If the latter, how does the pictureBox know the Bitmap has been modified? If the former, why doesn't my save contain the modification?

How can I save the modified Bitmap?

Comment: The title of your question is not precise. It should mention that it relates to Graphics objects in Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the loaded image into a new `Bitmap`, make your modifications to that bitmap, and then save it.

Something like (pseudo-code'ish):

```
// create bitmap and get its graphics
Bitmap^ pBmp = gcnew Bitmap(grabbedFrame->Width, grabbedFrame->Height);
Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(pBmp);

// draw grabbed frame into bitmap
g->DrawImage(grabbedFrame, 0, 0, grabbedFrame->Width, grabbedFrame->Height);

// draw other stuff
g->DrawEllipse(Pens::Red, 20, 20, 20, 20);

// save the result
pBmp->Save(photofile, System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageFormat::Jpeg);
```

Comment: Ah. I had tried that before, but Human Error had made it appear not to work. Finally, success!  I'm still confused, though. Isn't a bitmap a bitmap? Why do I have to make a different one? Thanks for your help!